Which Standard object has prefix `0Xx`?
Which Standard object has prefix 0Xx?
I was checking here https://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html but couldn't find it.

It didn't exist when that post was written

Nice thing though is that Daniel often updates it... seems there are some new entries needed!

@PhilW I was kind of surprised that Daniel's post contains nearly 900 more entries than my key scanning tool. I guess I shouldn't have been, considering he has insider access.

what is your key scanning tool? @sfdcfox

https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t41000000Um4f

That's an outdated version, I'll be uploading a new version once it's done. Basically, it makes an Id of every type (~240k different types, if I remember), and tries to get the sObjectType from each.

oh, you have a package, is it on AppExchange?

I've updated my page to include 0Xx. I've been careful not to include any internal knowledge in the contents of that page. It needs to be all content that was exposed publicly, such as via APIs and describe calls.

This is Bot Definition standard object, which corresponds to Bot metadata, deployed by Metadata API.

Suprisingly, it is not mentioned in the Object reference.


Once you know the Metadata type you can look it up in the Metadata Coverage report.

well, Metadata coverage report is about metadata, where I was looking for the corresponding data information
